# My webapp works fine on localhost, but not on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a simple ML model on Heroku but it keeps crashing and I can't find what's wrong with it.
I've tried different options on my Procfile, searched several questions here on Stack but they are mostly about Django and I'm using Python. Also, searched different tutorials and got the same error everytime.

**This is the Heroku log:**

```
2021-11-12T17:44:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user galliagustin@hotmail.com
2021-11-12T17:45:32.457806+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-11-12T17:45:32.195291+00:00 app[api]: Release v30 created by user galliagustin@hotmail.com
2021-11-12T17:45:32.195291+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 451ffa79 by user galliagustin@hotmail.com
2021-11-12T17:45:48.107548+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2021-11-12T17:45:49.468783+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-11-12T17:45:49.404749+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-12 17:45:49 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-11-12T17:45:49.405354+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-12 17:45:49 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:14807 (4)
2021-11-12T17:45:49.405421+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-12 17:45:49 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-11-12T17:45:49.417359+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-12 17:45:49 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-11-12T17:45:49.463354+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-12 17:45:49 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956153+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-12 17:45:52 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956175+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956176+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956177+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956177+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956178+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956178+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956178+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956179+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956180+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956180+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956180+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956180+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956181+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956181+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956182+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956182+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956183+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956184+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956184+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956184+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956185+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956185+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956185+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956185+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 12, in <module>
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956186+00:00 app[web.1]:     model = pickle.load(f)
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956186+00:00 app[web.1]: _pickle.UnpicklingError: NEWOBJ class argument isn't a type object
2021-11-12T17:45:52.956361+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-12 17:45:52 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961557+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-12 17:45:52 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961558+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961558+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961559+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961559+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961559+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961560+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961560+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961560+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961561+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961561+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961561+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961561+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961562+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961562+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961562+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961562+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961563+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961563+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961563+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961564+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961564+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961564+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961564+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961564+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 12, in <module>
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961565+00:00 app[web.1]:     model = pickle.load(f)
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961565+00:00 app[web.1]: _pickle.UnpicklingError: NEWOBJ class argument isn't a type object
2021-11-12T17:45:52.961731+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-12 17:45:52 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-11-12T17:45:53.082404+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-12 17:45:53 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 9 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-11-12T17:45:53.177339+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-12 17:45:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-11-12T17:45:53.177379+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-12 17:45:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-11-12T17:45:53.318014+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-11-12T17:45:54.088977+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-11-12T17:46:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

**This is my Procfile**

web: gunicorn app:app

**and my project structure**

webapp/

```
├── model/
│   └── bike_model_xgboost.pkl
├── templates/
│   └── main.html
├── requirements.txt
├── Procfile
└── app.py
```

Editet -  Here is the app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[ ]:


import flask
import pickle
import pandas as pd
# Use pickle to load in the pre-trained model.
with open(f'model/bike_model_xgboost.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)
app = flask.Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    if flask.request.method == 'GET':
        return(flask.render_template('main.html'))
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        temperature = flask.request.form['temperature']
        humidity = flask.request.form['humidity']
        windspeed = flask.request.form['windspeed']
        input_variables = pd.DataFrame([[temperature, humidity, windspeed]],
                                       columns=['temperature', 'humidity', 'windspeed'],
                                       dtype=float)
        prediction = model.predict(input_variables)[0]
        return flask.render_template('main.html',
                                     original_input={'Temperature':temperature,
                                                     'Humidity':humidity,
                                                     'Windspeed':windspeed},
                                     result=prediction,
                                     )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

any ideas or suggestions are more than welcome!

Comment: can you share your app.py

Comment: There I added the app.py! Hope it helps

Comment: are you able to run this locally outside of flask by tryingto just unpickle the object in a python repl?

Comment: Yup! I can run it locally with no issues at all. That's what's driving me crazy haha